# Образование прилагательного от слова "медиация"

Tags: словообразование

Уважаемые эксперты!
Буду признательна за ответ на такой вопрос: как правильно образовывается прилагательное от слова "медиация"?
Правильно ли я понимаю, что "медиац" - это основа и корень слова?
Заранее спасибо за ответ! :)
Владислава Каневская
Киев, Украина

Answer (score 1):

прилагательное - медиационный, -ая, -ое
Слово иностранное, русский суффикс обычно не выделяют, так что для практических нужд в русском языке можете считать "медиац" корнем слова.

Хотя вообще-то слово образовано от латинского "mediatio" с коренем "медиа" и суффиксом "tio"

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Добавлено 
К "медиация" прилагательное - медиационный.
Медиативный - к "медиатив", это специальный лингвистический термин, особый падеж в некотрых языках (косвенный творительный).

Путать не надо.

Answer (score 0):

Есть однокоренное слово "медиатор". Корень "медиа". Согласно, что прилагательное "медиационный". А может, медиаторский?

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо! 
По поводу образования прилагательного от слова "медиатор" - медиаторский - как-то вопросов нет. :)

И все-таки, как правильно образовать прилагательное от "медиация"?
Последние несколько лет некоторые практики в России начали утореблять форму "медиативный", в то время как ранее (уже лет 20!) применялось "медиационный"...
Уточнение: медиация - это процесс разрешения конфликта или спора с помощью нейтрального посредника (медиатора).
Тогда, например, "медиационный процесс" или "медиативный процесс"? :)
И да, слова "медиа", "медиатор" (музыкальный и специалист-посредник), "медиум", "медиация" имеют общий источник - слово "медиа".
Спасибо! :)

Comment: К "медиация" прилагательное - медиационный.
Медиативный - к "медиатив", это специальный лингвистический термин, особый падеж в некотрых языках (косвенный творительный). 

Путать не надо.